# How to properly use URL filtering with Next.js 13

Tags: next.js, contentful, next.js13

I need to implement URL-based filtering in my application.

My plan is to use a SSR (render, fetch and cache the data on the server-side)

I've created a static route that receives the query parameters as props:

```
export default async function Filter({ searchParams }) {
  const t = await getContentType();
  const f = getFilteredResults(searchParams, travelDestinations);

  return <TravelList travelDestinations={filteredResults} />;
}
```

When I build the app I've the first warn:
**- warn Entire page /travel/filter deopted into client-side rendering. https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/deopted-into-client-rendering /travel/filter**

As a consequence, the route is classified as static, rendered at build time and remains unchanged.
Contrary, imo, to what is referred by the documentation:
*[Good to know:
searchParams is a Dynamic API whose values cannot be known ahead of time. Using it will opt the page into dynamic rendering at request time.](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/page#params-optional)*

As a turnaround, I've used `export const dynamic = "force-dynamic";`
It then works as expected.
The issue now lies on the caching, as data is fetched on every incoming request to the server. I verified it by testing and is also written in the [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/caching#full-route-cache).

Could you please tell me if I have a design error that's leading me problematic situations ?

Thank you